# Design pattern to load image depending on screen resolution

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm adding images to screens depending on screen resolution. So depending on the screen resolution I add the approprate sized image. Does this fall into any design pattern? Or is there a design pattern that better suits this requirement ?

```
ImageFactory.getBitmap();

    public static Bitmap getBitmap(){   

        if(screenWidth == 360 && screenHeight== 480){
            return new Bitmap("360480.bmp");
        }
        else {
            return new Bitmap("320240.bmp");
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a factory pattern. Your factory is smart about which bitmaps to create/return by taking the screen size into account, and from what I'm seeing I think you are doing alright there.

While you are at it, you *might* want to think about the naming pattern for the images (I think something like "640x480.bmp" is easier to the eye than "640480.bmp").

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, in this particular case, you can get away with convention strategy (not as a design pattern).

Something like this:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap(){ 
    String fileName = Integer.toString(screenWidth)
        + Integer.toString(screenHeight) + ".bmp"

    File f = new File(fileName);  

    if(f.exists()){
        return new Bitmap(fileName);
    }
    else {
        return new Bitmap("320240.bmp");
    }   
}
```